# Python + SqlAlchemy 'init' with single table inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

got problems with a Sqlalchemy thing.

I've defined my database, relevant parts as per below...

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PERSON'
    #
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_type = Column(String(32), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(50))
    address = Column(String(120))
    phonenum = Column(String(20))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on':person_type}

#

class Student(Person):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'Student'}
    dob = Column(Date)
```

I've other subclasses of 'Person' too.  I'm having problems with the way the 'init' should look. My last attempt was..

for 'Person'..

```
def __init__(self, a_name, a_address, a_phonenum, a_person_type = None):
    self.name = a_name
    self.address = a_address
    self.phonenum = a_phonenum
```

and for 'Student'..

```
def __init__ (self, a_name, a_address,a_phonenum, a_dob=None, a_stud_caregiver_id=None, a_person_type = 'Student'):
    self.name = a_name
    self.address = a_address
    self.phonenum = a_phonenum
    self.dob = a_dob
    self.stud_caregiver_id = a_stud_caregiver_id
    self.person_type = a_person_type
```

- but though this creates the database ok, when I come to 'init' my students, I'm getting messages along the lines of...

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: Class object expected, got 'Table('PERSON', MetaData(bind=None)....

I've tried with/without the person_type parameter .. but really, I'm just shooting in the dark.

I've obviously done something dumb, but what?   Thanks!

Comment: generally, you want to call the base-class's init (or use `super`).  e.g. `Student.__init__(self,require,args)`.  I don't know if this is how it is for `sqlalchemy`, but this is pretty standard.

Comment: Also normally, you don't need to write an `__init__` with such basic functionality as SQLAlchemy already provides a keyword-argument-only constructor that simply assigns to the given attributes. If you need further logic, then implement that first and then (as suggested by @mgilson) add a call to be parent constructor: `Base.__init__(self, **kwargs)`.

Comment: I was able to create a database with these models (including the given constructors) without any problems. Can you give us a complete python script that we can run that duplicates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for comments all.  I left the INIT methods as I don't (yet) know whether to add in the person_type by hand or not.  Mark - I can create the database ok, I just can't load it with the INITs (be the mine or automatic).  Latest attempt was ...>>> new_student = Student("John Brown","1 High Street","09 123 4567") and this got me...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    new_student = Student("John Brown","1 High Street","09 123 4567")
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given